# Free membership auto-renewal

Tags: civimember

We have a few membership types that are "semi-automatic".  They are honorary memberships that we don't charge for, but we want them to renew manually because it's an opportunity for them to update their data and donate to the society.  So, officially, it's an annual membership that they have to renew themselves.

However not all of them do, and for those that don't we want to make sure they stay members.  In this sense it's a lifetime membership.

So what I need to do is find a nice way of doing a mass renewal of all those members of these types sometime after our regular renewal period is over. Which is now.

My best idea so far is to do a search for all expired members of each type, export them, and then use that exported data to import new memberships for those people.

It should work, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a Search for Memberships (eg Find Members, or Adv. Search but set to show results as Memberships) then you should have access to a Batch Update via Profile that I think lets you change Membership characteristics such as Status.

You will also need to create a Profile with the relevant Membership fields in it.

Comment: That's the sort of thing I was hoping for, thanks.  I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Back again... this might be useful for some things, but not this.  Unless I am missing something.  The batch is limited to 100 at a time, and we have many hundreds to update.  And each record still needs to have the new expiration manually set, so we will still have to "touch" each membership manually.  In this instance, I think it will be quicker to go with the export/modify/import approach.

Comment: Oh, wait.  I see the "copy" function that replicates the changed value to all others.  That will at least make it quick to do in several batches.

Comment: yes - you can do 100 at a time. otherwise you would either need to do a membership export/import - or do it via an sql query

Answer (score 1):

Similar to your idea, if you search for expired members, export them, and then update the file to adjust the expiration date, you can update the existing memberships rather than importing new memberships. The exported file will contain the membership ID, which can be used to update existing instead of importing new. (It just seems a little cleaner than creating a new membership).